# Unit Testing & Bug Repo for Vb.Net 2005

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, .net-2.0, bug-tracking

Working on a company using the .Net Framework 2 (vb6 and vb.net 2005) and a very rudimentary sourceforge setup, I'm kindof at a loss when I was tasked to "...find a suitable Open Source Unit Testing & Bug Tracking system..." for the team. Those were my superior's exact words.

I know about the Team Foundation Server's capabilities, but the company doesn't want to adopt it and instead go for an open source solution. Any ideas on the best system which are compatible with the code used by the dev. team?

Answer (score 0):

We too are using the .NET Framework 2 (VB.NET 2005) and have begun unit testing with the NUnit  unit-testing framework (since our client is unwilling to pay for TFS, etc.)

You can find out more information here:
http://www.nunit.org/

Hope that helps,
Jeff